# Polymer - binding core-style

Tags: javascript, css, binding, polymer

I was trying to be able to color an element based on the attribute. I know, that binding inside  is not supported, so I decided to try

```
<core-style id="block-elem">
:host {
    background-color:  {{g.bgcolor}};}
</core-style>
```

When I tried it with:

```
<polymer-element name="block-elem" attributes="bgcolor" noscript>
...
<script>
  CoreStyle.g.bgcolor = 'red';
</script>
```

everything worked. But what I really want to do is to create similar objects with different colors. So I tried

```
<polymer-element name="block-elem" attributes="bgcolor">
<script>
 Polymer('block-elem', {
  bgcolor: "",
  }
 );CoreStyle.g.bgcolor = bgcolor;
</script>
```

I am creating object with

```
<block-elem bgcolor="red">TEST</block-elem>
```

and nothing. Is it possible to implement that funcionality? Maybe there is another option which I didn't even think of.

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

If all you want is to style each element differently based on a
(possibly data bound) attribute.  Then it is simpler to use
an observer to set the elements style element instead of using the
core-style element.

```
observe: {
  bgcolor: function() {
    console.log("Setting color to " + this.bgcolor);
    this.style.backgroundColor = this.bgcolor; 
  }
}
```

But if you are want to do something more complex with core-style such as setting the theme of an element based on one attribute.  Then using a css attribute selector works in both chrome and in polyfill browsers (tested with firefox).

The below example shows the difference of using:

- global: changes all elements on the page at once.  Good if you want a 
  consistent theme across elements
- nested themes: my favorite but doesn't work in polyfill browsers currently
- css attribute selector: works across at least chrome and firefox on linux
- element styling: setting the each element style directly

### Components

```
<link rel="import" href="../../webcomponents/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../webcomponents/bower_components/core-style/core-style.html">

<!-- Based on ideas from https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-style.html -->

<!-- Using global sets all core-styles that use the global variable -->
<core-style id="demo-bindingcorestyle-style-global">
 :host {
   display:            block;
   background-color:   {{g.bgcolor}};
  }
</core-style>

<polymer-element name="demo-bindingcorestyle-global" attributes="bgcolor">
 <template>
  <core-style ref="demo-bindingcorestyle-style-global"></core-style>
    GLOBAL: This is a test trying to set the background to {{bgcolor}} but all elements share global and will be the last color
 </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      observe: {
        bgcolor: function() {
          console.log("Setting color to " + this.bgcolor);
          //  All elements get this global style
          CoreStyle.g.bgcolor = this.bgcolor;
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>


<!-- To specify different colors use a Common base style and then themed styles that can be changed -->
<!-- NOTE: id cannot use "-" in name if it is going to be used with list. syntax because it is treated as subtractions -->
<core-style id="demobindingcorestylestylecommon">
  :host {
   display:            block;
  }
</core-style>

<core-style id="demo-bindingcorestyle-style-red">
 {{list.demobindingcorestylestylecommon.cssText}}
 :host {
   background-color:            red;
   color:                       yellow;
  }
</core-style>

<core-style id="demo-bindingcorestyle-style-blue">
 {{list.demobindingcorestylestylecommon.cssText}}
 :host {
   background-color:            blue;
   color:                       white;
  }
</core-style>

<core-style id="demo-bindingcorestyle-style-green">
 {{list.demobindingcorestylestylecommon.cssText}}
 :host {
   background-color:            green;
   color:                       black;
  }
</core-style>

<polymer-element name="demo-bindingcorestyle-substyles" attributes="theme">
 <template>
  <core-style ref={{themename}}></core-style>
    Themed: This is a test trying to specify the theme as {{theme}} works in latest chrome with shadowdom but fails in polyfill browsers.
 </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      theme: 'blue',
      computed: {
       themename: '"demo-bindingcorestyle-style-"+theme'
      },
      observe: {
        theme: function() {
          console.log("Setting theme to " + this.theme);
          //  All elements get this global style
          //this.$.mystyle.ref = "demo-bindingcorestyle-style-" + this.theme;
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>


<!-- Using attribute selectors works both with shadowdom and polyfill -->

<core-style id="demo-bindingcorestyle-style-themeable">
 :host {
   display:            block;
  }
  :host([theme="red"]) {
    background-color:            red;
    <!-- Probably will want other themed color here -->
  }
  :host([theme="green"]) {
    background-color:            green; 
    <!-- Probably will want other themed color here -->
  }
  :host([theme="blue"]) {
    background-color:            blue;
    <!-- Probably will want other themed color here -->
  }
</core-style>

<polymer-element name="demo-bindingcorestyle-themeable" attributes="theme" noscript>
 <template>
  <core-style ref="demo-bindingcorestyle-style-themeable"></core-style>
    Themed: This is a test trying to specify the theme as {{theme}} it should actually work.
 </template>
</polymer-element>

<!-- Set background based on bgcolor attribute -->
<polymer-element name="demo-bindingcorestyle-justdoit" attributes="bgcolor">
 <template>
    Just set bgcolor: This is a test trying to set the background to {{bgcolor}} but all elements share global and will be the last color
 </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      observe: {
        bgcolor: function() {
          console.log("Setting color to " + this.bgcolor);
          this.style.backgroundColor = this.bgcolor; 
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

### Usage

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <script src="../../webcomponents/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="../../webcomponents/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="demo-bindingCoreStyle.html">
  <title>demo-bindingCoreStyle test page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Demo</h1>
  <h2>Using Global</h2>
  <demo-bindingcorestyle-global bgcolor="red"></demo-bindingcorestyle-global>
  <hr>
  <demo-bindingcorestyle-global bgcolor="green"></demo-bindingcorestyle-global>
  <hr>
  <demo-bindingcorestyle-global bgcolor="blue"></demo-bindingcorestyle-global>
  <h2>Using substyles</h2>
  <demo-bindingcorestyle-substyles theme="blue"></demo-bindingcorestyle-substyles>
  <hr>
  <demo-bindingcorestyle-substyles theme="red"></demo-bindingcorestyle-substyles>
  <hr>
  <demo-bindingcorestyle-substyles theme="green"></demo-bindingcorestyle-substyles>
  <h2>Using theming with attribute css selector</h2>
  <demo-bindingcorestyle-themeable theme="blue"></demo-bindingcorestyle-themeable>
  <hr>
  <demo-bindingcorestyle-themeable theme="green"></demo-bindingcorestyle-themeable>
  <hr>
  <demo-bindingcorestyle-themeable theme="red"></demo-bindingcorestyle-themeable>
  <h2>Just set background</h2>
  <demo-bindingcorestyle-justdoit bgcolor="blue"></demo-bindingcorestyle-justdoit>
  <hr>
  <demo-bindingcorestyle-justdoit bgcolor="green"></demo-bindingcorestyle-justdoit>
  <hr>
  <demo-bindingcorestyle-justdoit bgcolor="red"></demo-bindingcorestyle-justdoit>
 </body>
</html>
```